# Php.ini include_path and ssi

Tags: php, include-path, ssi

I have an ssi directory outside of my website webroot (var/www/shared/ssi)

I would like all differnet virtual hosts on the server to be able to access files in this directory so I added the path to include_path in php.ini

Now I can simply do the following to load ssi files in this directory.

```
<?php include 'header.htm'; ?>
```

My question is - is this good practice?  And should I be aware of any security implications of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to specify directory in your include sentence? Like `<?php include('/var/www/shared/ssi/header.html'); ?>`?

Comment: Is this a shared server, or are you the only one hosting sites on it? If it's a shared server, then anyone could potentially replace your header.htm with something malicious. Of course, they could probably do that anyways, but now you've provided a single place to deface all of your sites.

Comment: Yep, I don't want to hardcode it and since I have many virtual hosts which need to access ssi, it saves having to change the full path multiple times should it ever change.

Comment: Well I would rather hardcode the directory to my PHP script than to php.ini

Comment: Are you probably looking for [`virtual`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
<?php include 'header.htm'; ?>
```

will execute any PHP code inside `header.htm`. If you can't fully trust its contents, it's not a good idea. In that case, do

```
<?php readfile("header.htm"); ?>
```

this will read the file, *not* execute any PHP code in it, and output it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, this was my solution.

I set the include path temporarily for the script:

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/shared/ssi/');

And then use:

 <?php readfile("header.htm","true"); ?>

Thanks a lot